# How can I do environment migration for tfs?

Tags: tfs, migration

I am in a little bit confusing situation. Below diagrams are supposed to tell the case:

[image: Old Server Structure]

I had 2 different tfs servers serving to 2 different teams on my company. The users were local on those servers. So, no active directory, no central control. Hence we decided to merge these 2 servers into 1 TFS.

[image]

Now I have 1 big TFS server containing all the collections, without any problem at that level. But as you can see from the users names, the users are imported to this new server with their local computer names - `A\user1`, `A\user2`, `B\user3`, `B\user4`. Which violates my sense of harmony.

What I want to do is, install an Active Directory service on a new machine, and have all my users included in this new domain as below:

[image]

My ultimate goal is to use the same users, only changing their netbios names like `C\user1`, `C\user2`, `C\user3`, `C\user4`, in order to keep old informations in TFS valid.

Microsofts documentations calls the first step I have achived so far a "Hardware Migration", and the second step as "Environment Migration". Then tells to not to do them at the same time. So I completed, the hardware migration, and now I need to do the environment migration, but since I don't have a deep knowledge on this domain things I am taking it slowly.

I haven't installed Active Directory yet, since I don't know what I need to change beforehand.

**My questions are:**

1. What I am dreaming is possible?
2. How can I achive it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Environment-based migration scenario means changing the domain of the TFS deployment, whether it's a domain name change or going from a workgroup to a domain. So what you want can be achieved.

You can use [Identities command](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/command-line/tfsconfig-cmd#identities) to change the security identifier (SID) of users and groups in your deployment of TFS. This command supports the following scenarios:

- changing the domain of your deployment
- **changing from a workgroup to a domain** (your scenario) or from a domain to a workgroup
- migrating accounts across domains in Active Directory

Command:

```
TFSConfig Identities /change /fromdomain:DomainName1 /todomain:DomainName2 [/account:AccountName] [/toaccount:AccountName]
```

More information is described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404883(v=vs.120).aspx